# Select DateTime column of table in 24 hour format with sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a column `ReceivedOn` of type `DateTime`. I am executing a stored procedure with select statement like this:

```
Select 
    CONVERT(DateTime,ReceivedOn)[Date/Time], MessageText[Event] 
From 
    RawFeed 
Where 
    ATM = (Select Code From ATM Where ATM = @ATMID) 
    AND ReceivedOn Between @From And @To 
Order By 
    ReceivedOn Desc
```

I am storing stored procedure result in a DataTable object. and showing this object on my `.aspx` page

```
dtReturn = sspObj.ExecuteDataTable();
return dtReturn ;
```

`DataTable` object is converting into HTML table using some **function** storing result in table object and adding that to the page

```
tOutput = Generix.convertDataTable2HTMLTable(dtOutput, true, true, false);
Page.Controls.Add(tOutput);
```

But instead of displaying values as

```
2012-10-05 16:40:35.234
```

I get output like this:

```
2012-10-05 04:40:35 PM
```

Comment: You may post related code from : `convertDataTable2HTMLTable`. There you can format your dateobject using `.ToString("yourformat")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a SQL issue; SQL is returning a datetime, which is getting formatted by C# into the output you are seeing.  If you want SQL server to return a varchar (string) representing the date in your format, try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(24), ReceivedOn, 121)
```

See [Cast and Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Don't convert it, leave it as is.

```
Select ReceivedOn, ...
```

Comment: It gets printed in 24 Hour Format In SQL Server But Same does not reflect it in my .aspx page.

Comment: @Sagar I agree with John.  There are several reasons to have SQL Server just return the value in its native format (via Select ReceivedOn...) and have your C# code do the conversion; such as scalablility and re-use of code (when you want to use that stored procedure somewhere else but you want to display the date in a different format).  It is bad practice to have SQL Server decide the display format.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(Date,ReceivedOn,101))  + ' ' + 
convert(varchar,CONVERT(TIME,ReceivedOn)) AS ReceivedDate,
CONVERT(DateTime,ReceivedOn)[Date/Time], MessageText[Event] 
From 
RawFeed 
Where 
ATM = (Select Code From ATM Where ATM = @ATMID) 
AND ReceivedOn Between @From And @To 
Order By 
ReceivedOn Desc
```

Try this may this will help you....